# Property initial value to refer to Guid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, f#

I am building an F# ASP.NET MVC app, where one of my models looks like this:

```
namespace MyApp.Models

open System
open System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations

type ProductCategory() = 
    [<Key>] member val Id = Guid.NewGuid() with get, set
    [<Required>] member val Name = "" with get, set
    member val ParentCategory = Guid.Empty with get, set
```

Easy type for a product category where each category can have a parent (referenced by it Guid). Is this the correct way to declare the ParentCategory property? I have tried making it nullable or an option, without success, but as I'm new to all this I'm really lost with all these kind of details. I have tried searching but the furthest I got is that people declare it as Guid? in C#, which I am unable to do.

Any hints about the correct way to declare this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried `member val ParentCategory = Nullable<Guid>() with get, set`? Or `member val ParentCategory : Guid option = None with get, set`?

Comment: @ildjarn 's suggestion is correct, though I think the `option` alternative is more idiomatic.

Comment: I would have swore I had tried that @ildjarn... but it seems I didn't as it works perfect. I may had very well omitted the parentheses... I don't know, but thank you anyway, as it is what I needed. If you reply in a separate Answer I'll mark that as the correct one. Thank you again.

Comment: @RamonSnir, although I've been told option plays nice with C# (and as you say is the most idiomatic choice and the one I'd like to use), as this is mixed with EntityFramework and is my first project to get used to everything, I think I'll stick to System types for now. I'll probably try that in the future and see if it plays nicely or if it gives more headaches than benefits in a mixed C#/F# project. Thanks for the comment!

Comment: @JacoboPolavieja Since ildjarn hasn't posted an answer, it would be beneficial for you to post that as the answer and mark it as correct so others can more easily identify how you solved this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, based on @ildjarn answer, here it is how the final thing works:

```
namespace MyApp.Models

open System
open System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations

type ProductCategory() = 
    [<Key>] member val Id = Guid.NewGuid() with get, set
    [<Required>] member val Name = "" with get, set
    member val ParentCategory = Nullable<Guid>() with get, set
```

Thank you very much for helping!